# How to read azure devops variables in yml (yaml) as object and array data type

Tags: automation, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep, iaas

I am trying to create Azure resources like key vault using bicep and bicep parameter files.
I am using DevOps Pipeline for deployment. I am reading a few parameters from variable/ variable groups in .yml, which is used as param in bip file.
However, I want to read array and bicep objects from DevOps variable. Is there any way to achieve this?

Below is code snippet from .bicep file:

```
@description('Specifies the permissions to secrets in the vault. Valid values are: all, get, list, set, delete, backup, restore, recover, and purge.')
param secretsPermissions array

resource keyvault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' = {
  ---extra code---
    accessPolicies: {
        --extra code--
        permissions: {
          secrets: secretsPermissions
        }
      }
}
```

below is code from .parameters.json file:

```
"parameters": {
    "secretsPermissions": {
      "value": ["get","list"] //will prefer to get this from DevOps variable group
    }
```

below is code from yml:

```
overrideParameters: -<parameter_in_bicep> "$(<variable_in_variable group>)"
```

i want to read these variables as bicep object and array, currently I am only able to readall values as string only. even if i write them as array or object format.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to read these variables as bicep object and array, currently I
> am only able to readall values as string only. even if i write them as
> array or object format.

## The variables under pipeline concept only have one type - 'string'.

No other types, so you need to design code by yourself.

I write a python script demo in pipeline to help you get the content, add the item, update the content, remove the items of specific route in json file.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      #get json file parameters.json from Json_Files folder
      
      import os
      import json
      
      def add_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path, something_to_add, json_route):
          length = len(json_route)
          print(length)
          
          #open json file
          with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
              data = json.load(f)
              content = data
              #get the content f data[json_route[0]][json_route[1]]...[json_route[length-1]]
              for i in range(length):
                  if i == 0:
                      content = data[json_route[i]]
                  else:
                      content = content[json_route[i]]
              
              #add something to the content
              content.append(something_to_add)
      
              #write the data to json file
              with open(json_file_path, 'w') as f:
                  json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
      
      
      
              
      def remove_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path, something_to_remove, json_route):
          length = len(json_route)
          print(length)
          
          #open json file
          with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
              data = json.load(f)
              content = data
              #get the content f data[json_route[0]][json_route[1]]...[json_route[length-1]]
              for i in range(length):
                  if i == 0:
                      content = data[json_route[i]]
                  else:
                      content = content[json_route[i]]
              
              #remove something from the content
              content.remove(something_to_remove)
      
              #write the data to json file
              with open(json_file_path, 'w') as f:
                  json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
      
      def update_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path, something_to_update_from, something_to_update_to, json_route):
          length = len(json_route)
          print(length)
          
          #open json file
          with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
              data = json.load(f)
              content = data
              #get the content f data[json_route[0]][json_route[1]]...[json_route[length-1]]
              for i in range(length):
                  if i == 0:
                      content = data[json_route[i]]
                  else:
                      content = content[json_route[i]]
              try:
                  #update something from the content
                  content[content.index(something_to_update_from)] = something_to_update_to
              except:
                  print("something_to_update_from is not in the content")
      
              #write the data to json file
              with open(json_file_path, 'w') as f:
                  json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
      
      def get_json_content_of_specific_route_in_array_or_bicep_format(json_file_path, json_route):
          length = len(json_route)
          print(length)
          
          #open json file
          with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
              data = json.load(f)
              content = data
              #get the content f data[json_route[0]][json_route[1]]...[json_route[length-1]]
              for i in range(length):
                  if i == 0:
                      content = data[json_route[i]]
                  else:
                      content = content[json_route[i]]
              
              #get the content
              return content
      #==========================================Define the parameters=====================================#
      
      json_file_path = 'Json_Files/parameters.json'
      something_to_add = 'something_to_add'
      something_to_remove = 'something_to_add'
      
      something_to_update_from = 'list'
      
      something_to_update_to = 'something_to_add2'
      
      # route = ['parameters', 'secretsPermissions', 'value']
      route = ['parameters', 'secretsPermissions', 'value']
      
      
      #==========================================Run the function==========================================#
      
      add_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path,something_to_add=something_to_add,json_route=route)
      remove_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path,something_to_remove=something_to_remove,json_route=route)
      update_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path,something_to_update_from=something_to_update_from,something_to_update_to=something_to_update_to,json_route=route)
      print(get_json_content_of_specific_route_in_array_or_bicep_format(json_file_path,json_route=route))
```

For getting and changing data from YAML file, it is similar, or you can [convert the YAML to JSON](https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json) and then use above code.

This python code can convert yml file to json:

```
#convert yaml to json

import yaml
import json

with open('YAML_Folder/xxx.yml', 'r') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    with open('JSON_Folder/xxx.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

with open('JSON_Folder/xxx.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Original yml file:

[image]

After processed:

[image]